# Android Development: Open existing application in fragment

Tags: android

I need to create a scheduler application for an Android Tablet. Is there a way to use the existing android Calendar app in a frame/fragment. Example: The left side of the screen will have a list of unscheduled appointments pulled from a Content Provider. The right side of the screen should display a calendar (preferrably the out-of-the-box Calendar on the Android Device) with week and day views. Is it possible to do something like this with Android Development? If not, do you have any suggestions on how to proceed with this design?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might garner more responses if you were to show some research you've done on your own.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use the existing android Calendar app in a frame/fragment.

No. You are welcome to use the `CalendarView` widget, or various open source replacements, to render a calendar, but you cannot embed a third-party's UI in your own.